# Constructing a Worker with a string literal is not supported

Tags: javascript, web-worker, browser-extension

I'm constructing a worker like this:

```
state.worker = new Worker(
  "../../services/timeTracker/trackTimeWorker.js"
);
```

Using Plasmo want to build an extension off my vue project.
But I keep getting the error  `Constructing a Worker with a string literal is not supported`.

Is there a different way to build the worker? Or any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: I am guessing that the problem is the relative path you use. Have you tried using an absolute path?

Comment: Importing the file separately and using the import did the trick. I tried understanding the service worker api, but didn't figure how to activate the worker tho.

Comment: @temp can you provide the code you used there?